# DFS for finding Island Python

Tags: python, depth-first-search

I have been trying this approach for a little while and keep getting 0 for the count of islands. I am not quite sure what I am doing wrong here. As I have started learning python more and more so I may be missing something that is easy to spot.

So I want to find all the islands with a 1 in them and if they are connected (adjacent cells). So I want to return the count of the number of islands that are found.

Here is what I have so far.

```
def valid_direction(A, r, c):
    row = len(A)
    col = len(A[0])
    if r < 0 or c < 0 or r >= row or c >= col:
        return False
    else:
        return True

def dfs(A, r, c):
    A[r][c] = '1'
    # Up down left and right
    directions = [(0,1), 
                  (0,-1), 
                  (-1,0),
                  (1,0)] 
    for d in directions:
        nr = r +d[0]
        nc = c + d[1]
        if valid_direction(A, nr, nc) and A[nr][nc] == '1':
            dfs(A, nr, nc)


def solution(A):
    if not A:
        return -1

    row = len(A)
    col = len(A[0])
    results = 0
    for i in range(row):
        for j in range(col):
            if A[i][j] == '1':
                dfs(A, i, j)
                results +=1
    return results
```

And here are the two arrays I am working with

```
A1 = [[1,1,1,1,0],
      [1,1,0,1,0],
      [1,1,0,0,0,],
      [0,0,0,0,0]]

A2 = [[1,1,0,0,0],
      [1,1,0,0,0],
      [0,0,1,0,0],
      [0,0,0,1,1]]
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you want the result to be? You said, "I want to find all the islands with a 1 in them and if they are connected (adjacent cells)." However, `solution()` is only returning a single number (i.e. `results`). A single number can't represent your stated goal. Please provide an example of your desired output.

Comment: I edited it by adding this So I want to return the count of the number of islands that are found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made a simple mistake. Your arrays are arrays of integers, not chars.
`A[r][c] = '1'` and `A[nr][nc] == '1'` and  `if A[i][j] == '1'`
should be
`A[r][c] = 1` and `A[nr][nc] == 1` and `if A[i][j] == 1`
I'm not sure it will solve the question correctly after this, but this is the current error.

---

Your current code just counts the number of 1s.
You should check if the 1 is visited ex)by changing it to 2.
Also you don't have to initiate directions every time dfs is called you should just take it outside the function.

```
directions = [(0,1), 
              (0,-1), 
              (-1,0),
              (1,0)]

def valid_direction(A, r, c):
    row = len(A)
    col = len(A[0])
    if r < 0 or c < 0 or r >= row or c >= col:
        return False
    else:
        return True

def dfs(A, r, c):
    A[r][c] = 2
    # Up down left and right 
    for d in directions:
        nr = r +d[0]
        nc = c + d[1]
        if valid_direction(A, nr, nc) and A[nr][nc] == 1:
            dfs(A, nr, nc)


def solution(A):
    if not A:
        return -1

    row = len(A)
    col = len(A[0])
    results = 0
    for i in range(row):
        for j in range(col):
            if A[i][j] == 1:
                dfs(A, i, j)
                results +=1
    return results
```

I'm not completely sure what you are trying to solve, but I think the correct code is this.

Comment: It seems to be killing the stack with a maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object error, but the solution seems to work thank you

Comment: @MNM the recursion error is because with the original code, the adjacent cells will infinitely call `dfs()` at each other. Glad it helped.